# Intellij IDEA cannot resolve symbol on implicits (scala tagless final)

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, ide, implicit, tagless-final

I have some code using *tagless final* approach and found that Intellij IDEA couldn't recognize method from implicit class.

I have some type-classes here (`Functor`, `Apply`, `Applicative` etc.) and one `implicit class FunctorOps` with some helper methods for `Functor`. This code compiles but IDEA couldn't found `void` and `implicit Applicative`. Look at the errors:

> Cannot resolve symbol void:44

> No implicit arguments of type: Applicative[F_]:51

The code looks not too difficult:

```
trait Functor[F[_]] {
  def map[A, B](fa: F[A])(ab: A => B): F[B]
}

trait Semigroupal[F[_]] {
  def product[A, B](fa: F[A], fb: F[B]): F[(A, B)]
}

trait Apply[F[_]] extends Semigroupal[F] with Functor[F] {
  def map2[A, B, Result](fa: F[A], fb: F[B])(abr: (A, B) => Result): F[Result] =
    map(product(fa, fb))(abr.tupled)
}

trait Applicative[F[_]] extends Apply[F] {
  def pure[A](a: A): F[A]
}

object Implicits {

  final implicit class FunctorOps[F[_]: Functor, A](private val fa: F[A]) {
    @inline def map[B](ab: A => B): F[B] =
      F.map(fa)(ab)

    @inline def void: F[Unit] =
      F.map(fa)(_ => ())
  }
}

trait Random[F[_]] {
  def nextInt(n: Int): F[Int]

  def void: F[Unit]
}

object Random {
  import Implicits.FunctorOps

  def dsl[F[_]: Applicative]: Random[F] =
    new Random[F] {
      override def nextInt(n: Int): F[Int] = F.pure(scala.util.Random.nextInt(n))

      override def void: F[Unit] = nextInt(4).void
    }
}

object Foo {

  def dsl[F[_]: Applicative]: F[Unit] =
    Random.dsl.void
}
```

**My question:** is there any way to avoid this errors in IDEA or it is better to use for example *VS Code* with *Metals* or something else? Is there somethign works better with *tagless final*?

I use std lib and add compiler plugin in sbt for using `F` dot method syntax:

`addCompilerPlugin("org.augustjune" %% "context-applied" % "0.1.4")`

[Code with build parameters in scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/NZc3zBTISjWvoB5HNoUdPA)

screenshots:

[image]

[image]

My environment:

- **Intellij IDEA** version **2020.2.3** (with last stable **scala plugin**)
- OS: MacOS Catalina **10.15.7**

Comment: I would just use **metals** with whatever editor you prefer. **InteliJ** is famous for its false compilation errors, and the more _"advanced"_ or complex the code is, the more it tend to fail.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://monosnap.com/file/2msi8gcCEl8DF4kdVgfdwrwjJSTxyx Try File | Invalidate Caches/Restart.. | Invalidate and Restart. If problem remains please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL with a minimal sample project. Thank you.

Comment: @Andrey from your screenshot I got that you are using Intellij IDEA EAP (early access) version but I'm using last stable build (updated question). I downloaded this IDEA version and these wrong errors disappeared. Thank you for your try. I hope IDEA will keep correct behavior in future stable releases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior fixed in next stable **Intellij IDEA** version **2020.2.4** and works properly.